# Permission denied when installing package in anaconda

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip, anaconda

I have just installed an Anaconda for a new user in a multi-user Ubuntu system. Firstly, I use

> conda create -n xxx

to create a new environment. I use

> conda install pytorch

to install the package. However, after all the progress bars going to the end, a screen of errors occurred:

> 

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp4eyh8tw0'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpdax8y0k6'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpil2a3a6p'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpuznszxsu'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpqe5krav0'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpxlr7zmlm'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpwqe4_njm'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp9miwq4w7'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp8mu21eiv'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpef1n2gse'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp3q0hrgf5'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpneckvjpj'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp9ea9vtxm'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp55vz7ljm'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpxguwz2wn'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpafxd74g9'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp44nhjwyb'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp0y4pzb81'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmptdcml12g'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp67avh3vi'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpcwd8r2vs'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpkdrhfx0q'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpu29ifspk'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp0d0kv38f'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpbf7ham1f'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp_m8h8_bl'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp8me4x4o7'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp248m08nl'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpqyaac040'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpou9x88l6'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmppncx_x9u'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmppq_j2bcv'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp1vrq34ws'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpc230y2if'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp6smyrerm'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpib1zd7mn'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmpjnexo23y'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cph_tmp8rcloj9t'
```

I had a look at the path '/home/anaconda3/', there's lots of new files begin with 'cph_tmp'.

I then entered

> conda list

but the list shown is empty.

I then opened the dictionary of the environment, found there is only a folder named 'conda-meta', no 'bin' or other folders.

The permission of anaconda folder and its subfolders are *drwxrwxr-x*, which seems right.

I don't find the problem of the errors, I use anaconda in other users well. What can I do about that?